# How do I edit a group contact list in my Hotmail account now that it uses Outlook?

Tags: outlook.com

I was automatically switched to Outlook to manage my Hotmail account.  Now I want to edit contacts in a group and can't find any listings for any of the groups I made.  I can put them in the `TO:` box for e-mails but can't figure out how to access the names in the group.

Answer (score 1):

Go into People (from the top left of the page) and select from Groups at the top of the page. Groups you had in Hotmail should have been carried over for you already.

[image]

Comment: This has now changed, see this question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/no-longer-have-way-to-manage-groups-no-groups-listing-in-outlook-com

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the main menu by clicking the down arrow next to "Outlook"

   [image]
2. Select the "People" app

   [image]
3. Change the filter to be the group you want to work with by clicking the arrow next to "All"

   [image]
4. Now you have a list of all of the people in that group. You can use the checkbox next to each in order to select one or more contacts to remove them from the group, etc.

Note: As of May 2013, this has changed. There is no longer a filter/arrow by 'All', and the way you add and delete contacts is different. You now have to find your group amongst all the other contacts, click on it, then use the edit tab in the menu to add and delete contacts. As described in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/no-longer-have-way-to-manage-groups-no-groups-listing-in-outlook-com?rq=1).