# Accessing groups in Outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com

I can't access my groups on Outlook.com . When first transferred from Hotmail everything was fine and I was able to add / delete people from the groups I had created. Today the down arrow beside people has disappeared. Any suggestions?

Comment: This would seem to be the same issue: [no longer have way to manage groups; no "groups" listing in Outlook.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44234)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. By accident I found I could get a list of just groups in "People" by clicking on "Settings", and under "Filter All Contacts" I unticked Messenger and Outlook and that just left my Groups in the Left hand pane. Hope that helps temporarily.