# One of the tabs in Outlook.com contacts has gone missing

Tags: contacts, outlook.com

I run my own business and keep e-mail contacts in two groups: `a-j` and `k-z`.

Whenever I had a new contact I would simply add their name and then click on the GROUPS tab in the contacts sections.  That would bring down a drop box and I could add them to the appropriate group.  The "Group" tab is no longer there!  It disappeared a couple of weeks ago and I have no idea how to add people to a specific group now. The only options now are:

- New
- Manage
- Edit
- Delete
- Add to favorites

Could anyone help me on this one please?

Comment: You're not the only one. We've had several questions about the disappearance of the "groups" tab. Like this one: [no longer have way to manage groups; no "groups" listing in Outlook.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44234)